# Map<String, Object> from controller accessing the inner object

Tags: controller

Having and data returned from api like this:

```
    {
        "result": true,
        "retData": {
            "CATEGORY_A": {
                "MEALS": {
                    "price": "",
                    "active": "false",
                    "tax": "",
                    "price_history": [],
                    "label": ""
                },
                "SNACKS": {
                    "price": "",
                    "active": "false",
                    "tax": "",
                    "price_history": [],
                    "label": ""
                }

            },
            "CATEGORY_B": {
                "BODY_CARE": {
                    "price": "",
                    "active": "false",
                    "tax": "",
                    "price_history": [],
                    "label": ""
                },
                "TOOLS": {
                    "price": "",
                    "active": "false",
                    "tax": "",
                    "price_history": [],
                    "label": ""
                },
                "HARDWARE": {
                    "price": "",
                    "active": "false",
                    "tax": "",
                    "price_history": [],
                    "label": ""
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

And with sample controller like this:

```
    public with sharing class SampleController{

        public Map<String, Object> categoryA{set;get;}
        public Map<String, Object> categoryB{set;get;}
        public Map<String, Object> testObj{set;get;}
        public String test{set;get;}

        public void somthing(){

            Map<String, Object> jsonBody = (Map<String, Object>)JSONUtil.deserialize(policyResult.get('data'));
            String result = String.valueOf(jsonBody.get('result'));


            Map<String, Object> desData = (Map<String, Object>)jsonBody.get('retData');
            Map<String, Object> catA = (Map<String, Object>)desData.get('CATEGORY_A');
            Map<String, Object> mealObj = (Map<String, Object>)catA.get('MEALS');
            this.testObj = mealObj;
            String price = String.valueOf(mealObj.get('price'));

            this.categoryA = (Map<String, Object>)desData.get('CATEGORY_A');
            this.categoryB = (Map<String, Object>)desData.get('CATEGORY_B');
            this.test = price;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

In what way can I access the inner objects if this is how my controller looked? 
I cannot do {!categoryA.MEALS}. Is there any way or just break it in the controller? 
Im planning to use it in apex:repeat to dynamically create a table. Can someone enlighten?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `{!categoryA['MEALS']}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're putting your objects in a map, the correct syntax to reference values in a map in visualforce is:

```
{!categoryA['MEALS']}
```